# How to make a border-radius-ed connected navbar?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am making a react app and I have an odd looking navbar to make (shown in picture).
Any idea what kind of navbar it is called or how to design this?
[image]

Comment: basicly, you set the radius on the parent and use overflow. 101 example https://jsfiddle.net/c8Lf4qdb/2/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a normal navbar, Try This:

Navbar Componment

```
const NavBar = () => (
    <header className='navbar'>
        <div className='navbar__item active'>Home</div>
        <div className='navbar__item'>Social</div>
        <div className='navbar__item'>Events</div> 
<div className='navbar__item'>Pet Friendly Places</div> 
<div className='navbar__item'>Services</div> 
<div className='navbar__item'>About Us</div>        
    </header>
);
```

style

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius:50px;
    background: hsl(230deg 44% 26%);
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar__title {
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 150%;
    padding: 12px 16px;
}

.navbar__item {
    padding: 16px 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.active{
background-color:hsl(210deg 54% 40%);
border-radius:50px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

Comment: The active tab does not have borde radius on one side it looks weird with whole squared sides

Comment: I have edited the above snippet to

.active{
background-color:hsl(210deg 54% 40%);
border-radius:50px 0px 0px 50px;
}

Accept my answer if it worked as you expected :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    export const Nav = () => (
    <header className='navmenu'>
        <div >Home</div>
        <div >Social</div>
       <div >About Us</div>        
    </header>
);


//add this code on your css file
.navmenu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius:50px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).